# How to open external app from flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I expect the user to have installed microsoft teams, and when they press a button microsoft teams should be opened. I have tried `launch_url` but im not sure what i should pass to the launch function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just give a url of the site, so if wanna open Instagram you can just give this:

```
"https://instagram.com/"
```

if you have the Instagram app downloaded phone will ask you, Open it on the Instagram app or Instagram website? then user has to select the app and enjoy it.

**One more thing:** 
and we have one launch trick, so if you wanna directly send a message to an email
you can do this:

```
"mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=test%20subject&body=test%20body"
```

just replace your email in `test@gmail.com`